# onclick is not fired in a scrollable div

Tags: android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm not able to capture the click event on a div which is inside the scrollable div in some devices like Tab 3 and Galaxy grand. But it is working absolutely fine in other android devices.
My parent div has style

```
#parentDiv { overflow:true}
```

I have tried all methods like

```
$(document).on("click","#id"+i,function(){
    alert("tapped"); 
});
$(document).on("tap","#id"+i,function(){
    alert("tapped"); 
});
$(document).on("swipeleft","#id"+i,function(){
    alert("tapped"); 
});
```

where "id"+i are the dynamically generated divs inside parentDiv

Even I tried replacing the divs with "button" and "a" tag, still does not work

Comment: Also be sure the div exist in the dom at the moment the ready page triggers, if you are adding the div or parent dinamically the trick is to attach the click event inside the parent and filter by children, that way the click event is attached to an existent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have face similar problem and it is simple to solve, as you did not detail in case you are adding or midifying the divs dinamically.

Be sure the div exist in the dom at the moment the ready page triggers, if you are adding the div or parent dinamically the trick is to attach the click event inside the parent and filter by children, that way the click event is attached to an existent element.
The parent should exist since the beginning, if you are targetting the same event to all child divs use a class instead, if no your ids are ok.

Something like
$('#parentDiv').on('click', '.myClassDiv', function (){…});

Comment: hi, I'm adding the divs dynamically to already existing parent div.like->
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    attr1=getAttr();
    content +='<div id="id'+i+'" onclick=\'process("'+attr1+'");\'><p>'+value+'</p></div>' ;
    }

$("#parentDiv").append(content);

Comment: I said, use a custom class for the child divs, with that approach you don't need to use the onclick tag, appending to the parent is ok. Outside your loop just put a line like the one I put, that way the click event is attached to to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your problem, but I can give you an idea to debug the problem. I don't think, it is because of the scrollable HTML. What you can do is, while iterating the elements add an onlick attribute to with some alert statement. If it works the problem is somewhere in your script.

For example,

**JS**

```
var ele = '';
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  ele += '<a href="#" onclick="alert('+ i +')">element +' i '+</a>'
}
```

Comment: hi, I'm adding the divs dynamically to already existing parent div.like->
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    attr1=getAttr();
    content +='<div id="id'+i+'" onclick=\'process("'+attr1+'");\'><p>'+value+'</p></div>' ;
    }

$("#parentDiv").append(content);
Even this does not work